# Comment Link to OP not Possible

Tags: bug, comment-replies

I recently tried to address the OP of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/171702/19341) in a comment. The auto completion doesn't work (at least not for me).

How can I (theoretical) call him? Is this a general problem of user, having a name like "X Lalala"?

Comment: The username auto-completion (invoked by <Tab>) appears not to work if the username is redundant, because the target is already a default recipient. E.g. here @draks would be redundant, so it will not complete.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since no one else has commented yet, the only person you could be replying to is the OP, so the system removes your @-reply (and also will refuse to auto-complete it if you start typing it). See [this meta.SO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation/97099#97099) and the more general [info about @-replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks.

Comment: One important addition is that it *will* complete if other people participated in the comments thread as well.